# Pulling a Really Large Horseshoe in Space

Tags: general-relativity

Let's assume I have a horseshoe, that's about 1 light-second away from me at its maximum distance, but about 2 light-seconds in total length. The ends are extremely close, though not connected.

When I pull the horseshoe towards me using one end, what happens? Does the information transfer (by which I mean the fact that I pulled the horseshoe) occur along the length of the horseshoe, or its distance from me? I'm fairly sure either the far part of the horseshoe or the other end should have a delay due to the speed of light/information transfer. But which one has the delay in movement? (or if I'm wrong, what actually happens?)

Edit: I just realized that the movement should propagate at the speed of sound in the horseshoe. Assume the horseshoe's speed of propagation is the speed of light, obviously a hypothetical scenario.)

Answer (score 0):

Material constraints aside it should behave the same as a normal rubber horseshoe you you might see in discount horseshoe toss set. Why is this the case? Well like in your setup the speed at which energy is transmitted within the horseshoe is limited.
\begin{equation}
v=\sqrt{\frac{T}{m/L}}
\end{equation}

It might be interesting to consider how a horseshoe would appear from different inertial frames since it is required that the speed of light is constant in all frames. The problems one may then face are addressed by length contraction (one frame will actually see just a normal size horseshoe).

Comment: I'm talking in relativistic terms. The horseshoe was more of a way to help describe the overall shape of the object, it doesn't have to be actually a horseshoe of any particular material or linear density.

Comment: @IanNg I am supplying an every day example that should behave similarly to your system. If you don't believe me then what other relativistic effects take place in your problem besides a finite propagation speed of information (note this is equivalent to saying energy is transmitted at a finite rate)? If no other relativistic effects occur, we can find many classical system with the same properties (a rubber horseshoe/rod,  the golden gate bridge, iron man sunbathing, etc).

Comment: I think I get what you're talking about, but I was thinking in terms of, as you mentioned, the appearance of the horseshoe from different inertial frames. Like, if the Lorentz transformation causes the horseshoe to appear longer with respect to distance from me (frame obviously being me), or if it would appear that one end of the horseshoe is moving towards me before the other end starts moving. Similarly to what would happen if I pulled a rigid bar of relativistic size. If I misunderstood again, please let me know.